# D3 selection via mouseover

Tags: d3.js, selection, mouseover

I write all the "names" of the first-level children of my json-data in a DIV.
How can I color (say, in red) the corresponding an arc in the graph when I mouseover a name?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7ss0rbv/), code below.

```js
var width = 960,
    height = 700,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .range([0, radius]);

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 10) + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return 1; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });

// Keep track of the node that is currently being displayed as the root.
var node;

 var root = JSON.parse('{ "name": "flare", "children": [  {   "name": "analytics",   "children": [    {     "name": "cluster",     "children": [      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}     ]    },    {     "name": "graph",     "children": [      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}     ]    },    {     "name": "optimization",     "children": [      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}     ]    }   ]  },  {   "name": "animate",   "children": [    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},    {     "name": "interpolate",     "children": [      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},      {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}     ]    },    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}   ]  },  {   "name": "data",   "children": [    {     "name": "converters",     "children": [      {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},      {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},      {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},      {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},      {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}     ]    },    {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},    {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},    {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},    {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},    {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},    {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}   ]  },  {   "name": "display",   "children": [    {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},    {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},    {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},    {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}   ]  },  {   "name": "flex",   "children": [    {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}   ]  },  {   "name": "physics",   "children": [    {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},    {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},    {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},    {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},    {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},    {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},    {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},    {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}   ]  },  {   "name": "query",   "children": [    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},    {"name": "And", "size": 1027},    {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},    {"name": "Average", "size": 891},    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},    {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},    {"name": "Count", "size": 781},    {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},    {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},    {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},    {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},    {"name": "If", "size": 2732},    {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},    {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},    {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},    {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},    {     "name": "methods",     "children": [      {"name": "add", "size": 593},      {"name": "and", "size": 330},      {"name": "average", "size": 287},      {"name": "count", "size": 277},      {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},      {"name": "div", "size": 595},      {"name": "eq", "size": 594},      {"name": "fn", "size": 460},      {"name": "gt", "size": 603},      {"name": "gte", "size": 625},      {"name": "iff", "size": 748},      {"name": "isa", "size": 461},      {"name": "lt", "size": 597},      {"name": "lte", "size": 619},      {"name": "max", "size": 283},      {"name": "min", "size": 283},      {"name": "mod", "size": 591},      {"name": "mul", "size": 603},      {"name": "neq", "size": 599},      {"name": "not", "size": 386},      {"name": "or", "size": 323},      {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},      {"name": "range", "size": 772},      {"name": "select", "size": 296},      {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},      {"name": "sub", "size": 600},      {"name": "sum", "size": 280},      {"name": "update", "size": 307},      {"name": "variance", "size": 335},      {"name": "where", "size": 299},      {"name": "xor", "size": 354},      {"name": "_", "size": 264}     ]    },    {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},    {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},    {"name": "Or", "size": 970},    {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},    {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},    {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},    {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},    {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},    {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},    {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}   ]  },  {   "name": "scale",   "children": [    {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},    {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},    {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},    {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},    {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},    {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},    {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},    {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}   ]  },  {   "name": "util",   "children": [    {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},    {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},    {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},    {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},    {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},    {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},    {     "name": "heap",     "children": [      {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},      {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}     ]    },    {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},    {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},    {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},    {     "name": "math",     "children": [      {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},      {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},      {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}     ]    },    {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},    {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},    {     "name": "palette",     "children": [      {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},      {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},      {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},      {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}     ]    },    {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},    {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},    {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},    {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},    {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}   ]  },  {   "name": "vis",   "children": [    {     "name": "axis",     "children": [      {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},      {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},      {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},      {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},      {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}     ]    },    {     "name": "controls",     "children": [      {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},      {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},      {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},      {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},      {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},      {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},      {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},      {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},      {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},      {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},      {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}     ]    },    {     "name": "data",     "children": [      {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},      {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},      {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},      {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},      {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},      {       "name": "render",       "children": [        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}       ]      },      {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},      {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},      {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}     ]    },    {     "name": "events",     "children": [      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}     ]    },    {     "name": "legend",     "children": [      {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},      {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},      {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}     ]    },    {     "name": "operator",     "children": [      {       "name": "distortion",       "children": [        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}       ]      },      {       "name": "encoder",       "children": [        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}       ]      },      {       "name": "filter",       "children": [        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}       ]      },      {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},      {       "name": "label",       "children": [        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}       ]      },      {       "name": "layout",       "children": [        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}       ]      },      {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},      {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},      {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},      {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},      {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}     ]    },    {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}   ]  } ]}');

root.children.forEach(function(obj) { d3.select("#list").html(d3.select("#list").html() + "<br>" +obj.name); });



  node = root;
  var nodes = partition.nodes(root)
// .filter(function(d) {
//  return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.001 radians = 0.05 degrees
//     })
    ;
  
  var path = svg.datum(root).selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
      .on("click", click)
      .each(stash);

  d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
    var value = this.value === "count"
        ? function() { return 1; }
        : function(d) { return d.size; };

    path
        .data(partition.value(value).nodes)
      .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", arcTweenData);
  });

  function click(d) {
    node = d;
    path.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attrTween("d", arcTweenZoom(d));
  }


d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

// Setup for switching data: stash the old values for transition.
function stash(d) {
  d.x0 = d.x;
  d.dx0 = d.dx;
}

// When switching data: interpolate the arcs in data space.
function arcTweenData(a, i) {
  var oi = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
  function tween(t) {
    var b = oi(t);
    a.x0 = b.x;
    a.dx0 = b.dx;
    return arc(b);
  }
  if (i == 0) {
   // If we are on the first arc, adjust the x domain to match the root node
   // at the current zoom level. (We only need to do this once.)
    var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [node.x, node.x + node.dx]);
    return function(t) {
      x.domain(xd(t));
      return tween(t);
    };
  } else {
    return tween;
  }
}

// When zooming: interpolate the scales.
function arcTweenZoom(d) {
  var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
      yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
      yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
  return function(d, i) {
    return i
        ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
        : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); };
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

path {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="size"> Size</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="count" checked> Count</label>
</form>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDITS**

Just dawned on me I answered your question backwards :)

First I'd build your list in a more `d3`ish manner with data-binding:

```
d3.select("#list")
  .selectAll('div')
  .data(root.children)
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .text(function(d){
    return d.name;
  })
  // on mouse over, find all arcs
  // at given depth and color them
  .on('mouseover', function(d){
    d3.selectAll('.' + d.name + '_arc_1_depth')
        .style('fill', function(){
          // stash old color for revert
          d._oldColor = d3.select(this).style('fill');
          return 'red';
      });
  })
  // revert color
  .on('mouseout', function(d){
    d3.selectAll('.' + d.name + '_arc_1_depth')
        .style('fill', d._oldColor);
  });
```

Then when you build your arcs, give them a unique class name to find them later:

```
.attr('class', function(d){
  return d.name + '_arc_' + d.depth + '_depth';
})
```

---

Working code:

```js
var width = 300,
    height = 300,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .range([0, radius]);

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 10) + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return 1; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });

// Keep track of the node that is currently being displayed as the root.
var node;

 var root = JSON.parse('{ "name": "flare", "children": [  {   "name": "analytics",   "children": [    {     "name": "cluster",     "children": [      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}     ]    },    {     "name": "graph",     "children": [      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}     ]    },    {     "name": "optimization",     "children": [      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}     ]    }   ]  },  {   "name": "animate",   "children": [    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},    {     "name": "interpolate",     "children": [      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},      {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}     ]    },    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}   ]  },  {   "name": "data",   "children": [    {     "name": "converters",     "children": [      {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},      {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},      {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},      {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},      {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}     ]    },    {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},    {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},    {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},    {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},    {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},    {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}   ]  },  {   "name": "display",   "children": [    {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},    {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},    {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},    {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}   ]  },  {   "name": "flex",   "children": [    {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}   ]  },  {   "name": "physics",   "children": [    {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},    {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},    {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},    {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},    {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},    {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},    {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},    {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}   ]  },  {   "name": "query",   "children": [    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},    {"name": "And", "size": 1027},    {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},    {"name": "Average", "size": 891},    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},    {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},    {"name": "Count", "size": 781},    {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},    {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},    {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},    {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},    {"name": "If", "size": 2732},    {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},    {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},    {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},    {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},    {     "name": "methods",     "children": [      {"name": "add", "size": 593},      {"name": "and", "size": 330},      {"name": "average", "size": 287},      {"name": "count", "size": 277},      {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},      {"name": "div", "size": 595},      {"name": "eq", "size": 594},      {"name": "fn", "size": 460},      {"name": "gt", "size": 603},      {"name": "gte", "size": 625},      {"name": "iff", "size": 748},      {"name": "isa", "size": 461},      {"name": "lt", "size": 597},      {"name": "lte", "size": 619},      {"name": "max", "size": 283},      {"name": "min", "size": 283},      {"name": "mod", "size": 591},      {"name": "mul", "size": 603},      {"name": "neq", "size": 599},      {"name": "not", "size": 386},      {"name": "or", "size": 323},      {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},      {"name": "range", "size": 772},      {"name": "select", "size": 296},      {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},      {"name": "sub", "size": 600},      {"name": "sum", "size": 280},      {"name": "update", "size": 307},      {"name": "variance", "size": 335},      {"name": "where", "size": 299},      {"name": "xor", "size": 354},      {"name": "_", "size": 264}     ]    },    {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},    {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},    {"name": "Or", "size": 970},    {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},    {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},    {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},    {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},    {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},    {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},    {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}   ]  },  {   "name": "scale",   "children": [    {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},    {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},    {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},    {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},    {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},    {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},    {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},    {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}   ]  },  {   "name": "util",   "children": [    {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},    {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},    {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},    {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},    {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},    {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},    {     "name": "heap",     "children": [      {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},      {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}     ]    },    {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},    {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},    {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},    {     "name": "math",     "children": [      {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},      {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},      {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}     ]    },    {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},    {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},    {     "name": "palette",     "children": [      {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},      {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},      {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},      {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}     ]    },    {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},    {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},    {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},    {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},    {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}   ]  },  {   "name": "vis",   "children": [    {     "name": "axis",     "children": [      {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},      {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},      {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},      {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},      {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}     ]    },    {     "name": "controls",     "children": [      {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},      {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},      {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},      {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},      {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},      {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},      {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},      {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},      {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},      {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},      {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}     ]    },    {     "name": "data",     "children": [      {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},      {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},      {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},      {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},      {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},      {       "name": "render",       "children": [        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}       ]      },      {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},      {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},      {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}     ]    },    {     "name": "events",     "children": [      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}     ]    },    {     "name": "legend",     "children": [      {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},      {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},      {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}     ]    },    {     "name": "operator",     "children": [      {       "name": "distortion",       "children": [        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}       ]      },      {       "name": "encoder",       "children": [        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}       ]      },      {       "name": "filter",       "children": [        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}       ]      },      {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},      {       "name": "label",       "children": [        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}       ]      },      {       "name": "layout",       "children": [        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}       ]      },      {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},      {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},      {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},      {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},      {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}     ]    },    {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}   ]  } ]}');

d3.select("#list")
  .selectAll('div')
  .data(root.children)
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .text(function(d){
   return d.name;
  })
  .on('mouseover', function(d){
   d3.selectAll('.' + d.name + '_arc_1_depth')
     .style('fill', function(){
       d._oldColor = d3.select(this).style('fill');
       return 'red';
      });
  })
  .on('mouseout', function(d){
   d3.selectAll('.' + d.name + '_arc_1_depth')
     .style('fill', d._oldColor);
  });
  
  node = root;
  var nodes = partition.nodes(root)
// .filter(function(d) {
//  return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.001 radians = 0.05 degrees
//     })
    ;
  
  var path = svg.datum(root).selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
      .on("click", click)
      .attr('class', function(d){
       return d.name + '_arc_' + d.depth + '_depth';
      })
      .each(stash);

  d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
    var value = this.value === "count"
        ? function() { return 1; }
        : function(d) { return d.size; };

    path
        .data(partition.value(value).nodes)
      .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", arcTweenData);
  });

  function click(d) {
    node = d;
    path.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attrTween("d", arcTweenZoom(d));
  }

// Setup for switching data: stash the old values for transition.
function stash(d) {
  d.x0 = d.x;
  d.dx0 = d.dx;
}

// When switching data: interpolate the arcs in data space.
function arcTweenData(a, i) {
  var oi = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
  function tween(t) {
    var b = oi(t);
    a.x0 = b.x;
    a.dx0 = b.dx;
    return arc(b);
  }
  if (i == 0) {
   // If we are on the first arc, adjust the x domain to match the root node
   // at the current zoom level. (We only need to do this once.)
    var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [node.x, node.x + node.dx]);
    return function(t) {
      x.domain(xd(t));
      return tween(t);
    };
  } else {
    return tween;
  }
}

// When zooming: interpolate the scales.
function arcTweenZoom(d) {
  var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
      yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
      yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
  return function(d, i) {
    return i
        ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
        : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); };
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
}

form {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

path {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="size"> Size</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="count" checked> Count</label>
</form>
<div id="list"></div>
```

**ORGINAL ANSWER**

First I'd build your list in a more `d3`ish manner with data-binding:

```
d3.select("#list")
  .selectAll('div')
  .data(root.children)
  .enter()
  .append('div') // place a dive
  .attr('id', function(d){
    return d.name;
  }) // with a unique name
  .text(function(d){
    return d.name;
  });
```

Then add a `mouseover` and `mouseout` to your arcs:

```
  .on("mouseover", function(d){
    d3.select('#list>#' + d.name) // find my div in my list by it's id
        .style('background-color', color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name));
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d){
    d3.select('#list>#' + d.name)
        .style('background-color', 'transparent');
  })
```